# Tag synonym proposal: [archeology] and [archaeology]

Tags: support

Please make [archeology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archeology) and [archaeology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archaeology) tag synonyms. Otherwise a single word is represented twice with variant spellings.

Comment: Why not obliterate [one](https://web.archive.org/web/20091205105622/http://www.saa.org/ForthePublic/Resources/OtherUsefulResources/Whyaretheretwodifferentspellingsarchaeology/tabid/1078/Default.aspx)? (But otherwise supportive)

Comment: @LangLangC Interesting article!

Answer (score 1):

I favor [archaeology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archaeology) as the main tag and the other as the synonym. Vote accordingly.